# Syntax for plural label

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, plural

In view of 5.7 laravel app with I want to number of items considering plural, like

```
{{ count($activeVoteCategories) }} vote @if(count($activeVoteCategories) > 1)s @endif
```

But resulting label is invalid, as there is unnessary space before last "s" symbol:

```
6 vote s
```

If I try to get rid of this space like

```
  {{ count($activeVoteCategories) }} vote@if(count($activeVoteCategories) > 1)s @endif
```

I got error :

```
syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file (View: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/
```

I know that there are plural methods in localization functionality, but this site has no localization, it it always in english...

which is the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just use `str_plural('vote', count($activeVoteCategories))`?